Winter Bash - In or Out?
Just like last year and the year before, we should decide whether we want the site participating in Winter Bash (hint: we always did). During Winter Bash, users earn virtual hats by completing certain tasks. They're sort of like badges, but they're more visible and less permanent. Hats can be "worn" on users' avatars just about anywhere avatars show up on the network.
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage. 
The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.
Please vote to the options below, we need to give our choice to the SE team by December 10, 2015!
EDIT: Now you can see our hats here.

Thanks for doing this survey!

And who doesn't love hats? :)

Also on a side note I believe hats start on December 15th, according to what I've read on a Unix & Linux post.

@kos This year's event will start on 14 December 2015 and run up to and including 03 January 2016.

Thanks, the date on the other post must be wrong then.

AYE! Of course, we want it, why do you ask?

NAY! Don't you see we are serious people here - why do you ask?
